# Attempted import error: 'EasingNode' is not exported from 'react-native-reanimated'

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

I am using @react-navigation/stack in my expo app and everything has been working fine. I wanted to start to add tab/drawer navigation to my app and keep running into the following 2 errors when I try to import

```
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
```

```
Attempted import error: 'EasingNode' is not exported from 'react-native-reanimated'.
```

and

```
Attempted import error: 'Appearance' is not exported from 'react-native-web/dist/index'.
```

The following is my package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.2.16",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.16",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.4.0",
    "expo": "~38.0.8",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "~3.0.7",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I've gone as far as creating a whole new expo app the solve this problem-but I still hit a wall once I import the bottom/top tab navigators. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Does the app still compile/run? I get that same warning but I can still use the tab navigators and the app still compiles and runs fine.

Comment: any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade `react-native-paper` to `4.0.0-alpha.1` solved my issue. It seemed like `expo@38.0.0` was incompatible with `react-native-paper@^4.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

node_modules\react-native-floating-label-input\src\index.tsx

```
import Animated, { EasingNode, timing, interpolateColors } from 'react-native-reanimated';
```

Replace the file with the following and it will be fixed.

```
import Animated, { Easing as EasingNode, timing, interpolateColors } from 'react-native-reanimated';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).